# Kubeflow cannot contact profile controller

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, kubeflow

Iam using an IBM bare metal machine. Using IBM's guide i have created a kubernetes cluster and logged on from my bare metal machine. Installed kubeflow and it was succesful no errors what so ever.
But when ever i try to access the kubeflow dashboard i get the following error shown in the image below.

[image]

I am not using LoadBalancer because IBM doesnt support one. At the moment i am using a NodePort type and use the following command to port forward. 
`kubectl port-forward svc/istio-ingressgateway 8080:80 -n istio-system`

I have read that is possible to use metallb as load balancer on baremetal kubernetes. Tried installing it but the whole cluster was messed up and i coulnt even get to the dashboard shown above.
Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Where did you see that IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service doesn't support LoadBalancer services? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-loadbalancer-qs

Comment: Can you check the profiles-deployment pod logs in kubeflow namespace within the cluster? I think it might help you the details of your problem: `kubectl logs {profiles-deployment-pod-name} -n kubeflow -c manager`. Also can you check that all `istio` components within the `istio-system` namespace are running. `kubectl get pods -n istio-system`